# adb logcat disconnects after 2 hours of inactivity Android

Tags: android, adb

On Android 12 Pixel 4a . I have an error that takes a few hours to reproduce. The issues arose after more than 5 GB files are downloaded. This takes a few hours and hence, I need to save adb logs until the issue is reproduces which may take a few hours.

```
adb -s 17281JEC213806 logcat > pixel_hub7.log
```

I use the above command to write adb logs into a file, this works well but after an hour of inactivity on my Windows System and device the adb automatically disconnects. Hence, I cannot get logs when the issue ours.

Although when I check the device after a few hours, it's still connected via adb but the adb logcat command is terminated after a few hours. My device is never disconnected from adb, only the abd logcat command gets terminated after an hour or so.

**Problem **: Is there a way I can ensure the adb logcat does not terminate after a few hours ?

I have tried the following in Device (Pixel 4a Android 12) developers Options:

- Stay awake when charging
- disable adb authorization timeout (enabled)